# CSS media query img max-width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a style sheet with lots of conditional media query statements. ranges from iPhone resolution to 1600px. However i want to make img inside a particular div fluid as if re sizes when browser window get resize, regardless of already written conditional @media query statement. i tried using

```
img { max-width: 100%}
```

But it doesn't work at all, the images remain as it is regardless of the browser widows. to make it effective i added !important as well at the end of the property and even pasted inside all the media query statements from iPhone resolution to 1600px, but it doesn't work.

How do i make such effect regardless of already written media query, i want the image to get flexible within a certain div, when the browser window changes.

i added

```
#inner_container img { max-width:100% !important; }
```

at the end of this style sheet

http://strongcodelabs.com/test/css/style.css

Comment: If you want to make it fluid, it should be `width: 100%` and not `max-width`.

Comment: but when making width: 100% it will cover whole div, i first want the image to have actual dimension in normal resoultion and when window resizes then minimizes its width and height accordingly.

Comment: To make it fluid, use `width: 100%`. To make it have original dimensions, use `width: auto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to resize for smaller screens and not scale the image up on bigger screens, this should be enough:

```
#inner_container  img{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Add it outside any media query and make sure the values don't get overwritten by any styles after them, use `!important` if needed.

Comment: Can you post a link yo your site to try to find the problem?

Comment: http://strongcodelabs.com/test/inner.html 

here notice the images at the end of the content container.. it should get resized, its not working now

Comment: Try adding `max-width: 100%;` to `#inner_container_main` in your global CSS, this will make the images adjust size but only when they wrap to two rows and the container is small enough

Comment: nope.. you mean .. #inner_container_main img { max-width:100% } right?

Comment: no, add the rule to the container itself, not the img, so just #inner_container_main { max-width:100% }